# Polymer Core Animation on Finish handler imperatively

Tags: polymer

```
  var animation = new CoreAnimation();
  animation.duration = 500;
  animation.keyframes = [ {opacity: "1"},{opacity: "0"}];
  animation.target = self.myElement;
  animation.play();
```

How to catch the finish event imperatively?

```
    self.myElement.addEventListener('core-animation-finish', function(e) {
              console.log('finish!');
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem, your code seems to do what you are asking for?

Comment: It is not working, when listening to "core-animation-finish" nothing happens. I was wondering if there is some callback in play method or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
 var animation = new CoreAnimation();
  animation.duration = 500;
  animation.keyframes = [ {opacity: "1"},{opacity: "0"}];
  animation.target = this.$.myElement;
  animation.play();

animation.addEventListener('core-animation-finish', function(e) {
              console.log('finish!');
 });
```